# jQuery: How do I affect only the child element of the element I clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some dropdown menus that all have the same class. When I click the dropdown, the submenu appears underneath. The problem is that after adding a second dropdown, when I click on either of them, both submenús appear. I have tried using different applications of $(this) with no success...

```
$('.dropdown').click(function() {

        $('.subdropdown').toggleClass("select");
});
```

"dropdown" is the parent element. When I click it, all subdropdowns are toggled.

Answer (score 2):

Use `$(this).find()` for descendants or `$(this).children()` for direct child elements:

```
$('.dropdown').click(function() {
    $(this).find(".subdropdown").toggleClass("select");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an instance of `this`

```
$(".subdropdown", this).toggleClass("select");
```